# How can i target closest element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to target the closest element of input field on keyup.

```
  <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="date_of_birth" name="date[]" value="">
     <span class="stepbirthVal"></span>
   </div>
```

i want to target stepbirthVal i tried by doing this in JS

```
var item = $(this).find('.stepbirthVal')
```

**i also tried this**

```
var item = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('stepbirthVal');
```

Can you please help me how can i target closest element.

Thanks

Comment: what `this` is referring to?

Comment: input with class date_of_birth

Comment: You're just missing a `.` for *class*: `.find('.stepbirthVal')`

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

If you want to find out by class

```
$('.date_of_birth').next('.stepbirthVal');
```

If you want to find it on input event lets say onFocus:

```
$(this).next('span.stepbirthVal');
```

You can be more precise by finding element with class *('span.stepbirthVal')* like this. There are various other ways depending upon situation.

Comment: Even if a 2-way trip, going for `.closest()` and than back inside with `.find()` - is always a better and  bulletproofer solution than doing `.next()`. Parent/child relations don't change so often, and even if changes JS will not suffer. On the other hand - HTML siblings can change more often (all it takes is to reorder HTML elements) resulting in a bugged application because `.next()` is not *next* any more.

Comment: I agree with you on that .find() is always a better approach as even if you change the dom order it will work. that's why I said there are various ways depending upon the situation.